# Django template {% with %} using variable as object value

Tags: django, templates, variables, object

I have a django template where I'm assigning a value to a template variable but I need to use that value to access a specific object. Ie:

```
  {% with operations.type as type %}
    {{ models.{{type}} }} <!-- HOW DO I DO THIS? -->
  {% endwith %}
```

Is there a tag/filter that I'm unaware of? Thanks.

Really in the template I just want to do:

```
type = "MyType1"
data = models.type
```

My data looks like (json):

```
{
   "models": {
      "MyType1": { "data": "somemoredata" },
      "MyType2": { "data": "somemoredata" },
      "MyType3": { "data": "somemoredata" },
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you have to do custom filters.

Comment: First rule — do not put the logic into templates. Only into views.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but you can make a [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/) and do something like:

```
@register.filter(name='getattr')
def get_a_field(obj_id, attr_str):
    my_obj = MyModel.objects.get(id=obj_id)
    return getattr(my_obj, attr_str)

{% with operations.type as type %}
    {{ models|getattr:type }}
  {% endwith %}
```

Comment: Cool thanks. I think that puts me in the right direction. However I'm getting an error saying: "'dict' object has no attribute 'MyTypeValue'" -- it definitely does.

Comment: I passed the object which likely ends up getting serialized. You could either just grab the value dict style or pass the object ID to the filter and get the object there

Comment: Sorry. I'm not totally following. "type" is really an index within this object

Comment: Updated my answer with the second option I mentioned

Comment: Hrm ok. So all I'm really trying to do is:

Comment: Yea, you can't do that in a template. You either need to make a filter or do the logic in the view and pass the result through the template context.